# Regular expressions cannot be used to express context free grammars. Is there a similar notation that can?

Tags: context-free, regular-expressions

Regular expressions are a powerful practical tool for string processing. But there are simple examples of useful string processing tasks (like, say, removing brackets from an expression `(E) -> E` when `E` might itself contain brackets) which cannot be represented by a convenient regular expression.

Is there a language of expressions that can be used to conveniently process patterns defined by a context-free grammar?

Answer (score 1):

Most domain-specific languages for context-free grammars are some variant of [Backus-Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) (BNF). A number of popular programming languages have BNF modules, like python's `pyparsing` module. They are also a first-class entity in the Raku programming language (a variant/successor to Perl) - see [Raku rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raku_rules). More commonly, you can write BNF grammars for various parser generators and then consume the generated parsers from a language of your choice.